# Using the subscript [] operator in inherited template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a template class `Array<T>` with the following three member functions defined.

```
template <typename T>
const T& Array<T>::GetElement(int index) const {
    if(index_out_of_bounds(index)) throw OutOfBoundsException(index);
    return m_data[index];
}

template <typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator [] (int index) {
    if(index_out_of_bounds(index)) throw OutOfBoundsException(index);
    return m_data[index];
}

template <typename T>
const T& Array<T>::operator [] (int index) const {
    if(index_out_of_bounds(index)) throw OutOfBoundsException(index);
    return m_data[index];
}
```

Next I have another template class `NumericArray<T>` that inherits from `Array<T>`. This class contains an overloaded operator `+`.

```
template <typename T>
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator + (const NumericArray<T> &na) const {
    unsigned int rhs_size = this -> Size(), lhs_size = na.Size();
    if(rhs_size != lhs_size) throw SizeMismatchException(rhs_size, lhs_size);

    NumericArray<T> array_sum(rhs_size);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rhs_size; i++) {
        array_sum[i] = this[i] + na[i];
    }

    return array_sum;
}
```

Now suppose I instantiate two instances of `NumericArray<T>` in main.cpp
where T is of type `int`. Both instances have already been populated with integer values.

If I now try to perform the `+` operator I get the following error message:

> ../NumericArray.tpp:44:16: error: cannot convert ‘NumericArray’ to ‘int’ in assignment
>      array_sum[i] = this[i] + na[i];

However, if I go back and change the implementation in the for loop of the overloaded `operator+` in `NumericArray<T>` to the following. The operator does as expected.

`array_sum[i] = this -> GetElement[i] + na.GetElement[i];`

Why is the subscript operator `[]` not behaving the same if they have equivalent implementations?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, not an object.  Operator overloading works on objects, which implies you have to dereference the pointer to get the object, no?

Comment: I just face palmed so hard.

Comment: Also, if you have a copy constructor, it would be much better to overload `+=` and then call `operator +` in terms of `+=`.  Then the code becomes a one-liner for `+`.  `return NumericArray<T>(*this) += na;`

Comment: As an aside, consider rewriting your non-`const` member's body to `return const_cast<T>((*this)[i]);`. Reducing duplication is good. Also, they should probably all be defined in-class.

Comment: On the plus side, if `*this` is a member of an array, `this[i]` isn't always nonsense.  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're attempting to apply `operator []` on a pointer type:

```
 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rhs_size; i++) {
        array_sum[i] = this[i] + na[i];
```

Since `this` is a pointer, you must either

1) dereference the pointer first to apply the overloaded operator.

or

2) apply the `->` operator and use the `operator` keyword to access the overloaded operator.

Here is an illustration of the two possible solutions:

```
    array_sum[i] = (*this)[i] + na[i];
```

or

```
    array_sum[i] = this->operator[](i) + na[i];
```

with the second solution, the `this` is not necessary:

```
    array_sum[i] = operator[](i) + na[i];
```

Comment: I believe in the 2nd solution one could remove `this->`.